# Creating a key value list with nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

So I have a script that checks each page in a PDF file and then on each page, divide the text of the PDF file into columns.

Consider below columns:

```
{"1":{"position":"15"}, "2":{"position": "50"}}'
```

```py
pages = {}
npages = 2 #Number of pages in the PDF.
for n in range(npages):

    pages[n + 1] = []

    for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):

        out = "Page n Column 1 Text Column 2 Text" #Simplified string.
        pages[n + 1].append({int(i + 1): str(out)})
```

My assumption was that this would create a key value pair, like:

```
page n: text inside the column
```

For some reason though, the above script creates a pair like this:

```
{1: 'Page 1 Column 1 Text'} - {2: 'Page 1 Column 2 Text'}
{1: 'Page 2 Column 1 Text'} - {2: 'Page 2 Column 2 Text'}
```

As you can see, it creates the key like:

```
{1: 'Page 1 Column 1 Text'}
```

Let's say I wanted to do this: (the output values are for the first iteration)

```py
for page, column in pages.values():
    print("Page: {}".format(page)) #Should output: Page: 1
    print("Column Text: {}".format(column)) #Should output: Column Text: Column 1 Text
```

To sum it up, my desired output is (where the page number is the key, and the column text is the value):

```py
{1: 'Page 1 Column 1 Text'}
{1: 'Column 2 Text'}
{2: 'Page 2 Column 1 Text'}
{2: 'Column 2 Text'}
```

What am I missing? I apologize if this is basic, I am new to Python.

Comment: @Sanyash I've updated my question - sorry if it is a bit unclear!

Comment: don't you want `pages[n + 1].append({int(n + 1): str(out)})` instead?

Comment: So you want a different dictionary per column?

Comment: @BillF No, I want the `column index` nested under the `page index`. So for example, on page 1 I have defined 2 columns. I want to be able to print for example: on page `1`, I have columns with `columntext1` and `columntext2`

Comment: @smac89 not sure if it's a different dictionary? I am trying to make an associative array, with page index and column indexes.

Comment: You do realize that in a dictionary, the keys are unique so there is no way to have the same key (page number) map to multiple values (columns). You may want to pay attention to what Bill is saying in the above comment

Comment: But how is it possible then in Python to create an associate array with key value pairs (page no, column no:column text)? Sorry, but I am very confused with lists and dictionaries. What Bill is suggesting does not add the column index

Comment: You could have a `list` in a dictionary such as `{1: ['Page 1 Column 1 Text', 'Column 2 Text']}`

Comment: @tgikal Would I be able to iterate through the pages to get the different columns? Would love an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really seems like you just want a list for your pages:

```
pages = []
npages = 2  # Number of pages in the PDF.
COLUMNS = ["example1", "example2", "example3"]
for n in range(npages):

    for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):
        if i == 0:
            pages.append({n + 1: "Page {} Column {} {}".format(n + 1, i + 1, col)})
        else:
            pages.append({n + 1: "Column {} {}".format(i + 1, col)})
```

Pages will then be defined as:

```
[{1: 'Page 1 Column 1 example1'},
 {1: 'Column 2 example2'},
 {1: 'Column 3 example3'},
 {2: 'Page 2 Column 1 example1'},
 {2: 'Column 2 example2'},
 {2: 'Column 3 example3'}]
```

---

**Update per comments:**
A list is not the ideal way to parse the contents in this manner - a dict of dicts would make a lot more sense if you're attempting to access each page's column contents.  For example:

```
pages = {}
npages = 2  # Number of pages in the PDF.
COLUMNS = ["example1", "example2", "example3"]
for n in range(npages):
    page_name = "Page {}".format(n + 1)
    pages[page_name] = {}
    for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):
        column_name = "Column {}".format(i + 1)
        pages[page_name][column_name] = col
```

Results in pages defined as:

```
{
    'Page 1': {
        'Column 1': 'example1',
        'Column 2': 'example2',
        'Column 3': 'example3'
    },
    'Page 2': {
        'Column 1': 'example1',
        'Column 2': 'example2',
        'Column 3': 'example3'
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted in your **updated** answer is exactly what I was trying to achieve! Thank you so much!